# Issues in validating custom code in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to implement a text field validation for field name VoucherNumber that requires the code to be in a certain pattern which is 'WWV-'followed by 4 numbers.
I was successfully able to implement this on google docs using the following expression `^[W]WV-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.

I researched through various answers and attempted to add this code in functions.php but it didn't work. It would just show that the form is being sent (spinning wheel) but it would not be sent even after 5 minutes.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'validate_voucher_number', 20, 2 );
  function validate_voucher_number( $result, $tag ) {
  $tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );
  if ( 'VoucherNumber' == $tag->name ) {
      $VoucherNumber = isset( $_POST['VoucherNumber'] ) ? trim( $_POST['VoucherNumber'] ) : '';
      if ( ! preg_match ( "^[W]WV-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ,  $VoucherNumber) ){
      $result->invalidate( $tag, "Voucher number is invalid" );
  }
  }
 return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your field name is VoucherNumber and try this code :

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'vouchervalidation', 20, 2 );

function vouchervalidation( $result, $tag ) {
 if ( 'VoucherNumber' == $tag->name ) {
    $VoucherNumber = isset( $_POST['VoucherNumber'] ) ? trim( $_POST['VoucherNumber'] ) : '';

    if ( ! preg_match ( "^[W]WV-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ,  $VoucherNumber) ){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Voucher number is invalid" );
    }
 }

 return $result;
}
```

Comment: I changed the field name to 'voucher' for simplicity's sake, but turns out this code is not validating the field, it accepts an invalid response too (ignoring case lock on the first three letters, accepting any response even if it doesn't match the validation rule). I inserted the code towards the end of the functions.php file and also tried it to paste it towards the start, still it would not validate.

Comment: Does your preg_match is correct because i have doubt that it must be not going into your if condition

Comment: I'm using this code ' add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'vouchervalidation', 20, 2 );

function vouchervalidation( $result, $tag ) {
 if ( 'voucher' == $tag->name ) {
    $voucher = isset( $_POST['voucher'] ) ? trim( $_POST['voucher'] ) : '';

    if ( ! preg_match ( "^[W]WV-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ,  $voucher) ){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Voucher number is invalid" );
    }
 }

 return $result;
} '